# MacOS: Any way to hide window title and not toolbar item labels?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, nswindow, appkit

I'm trying to make an app very similar to Apple's Mac OS App Store where the window's title is not visible but it has a toolbar with icons and labels.

[image: App Store]

The problem is that when I set the window's title visibility to hidden in my Window Controller, it also hides the toolbarItem labels.

```
window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
```

I tried explicitly setting the toolbar to show both icons and labels, but it seems to be ignoring this.

```
toolbar.displayMode = .iconAndLabel
```

Here is a screenshot of my app both with and without setting the title visibility:
[image: Setting titleVisibility to .hidden]
[image: Without setting titleVisibility]

Answer (score 1):

You can do instead of

```
self.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
```

the following

```
self.window.title = "" // no title but the labels for toolbar icons are there
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still leaves a blank space where the title should be and doesn't reduce the height of the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

you'd need  to start with a 'raw'/borderless nswindow and you'd have to draw it all yourself. there is a nice INAppStoreWindow (or it was nice 4 yrs ago ;)) on github that does all to mimic the appstor look and feel

Comment: Thanks for the info, although it looks like INAppStoreWindow hasn't been maintained in years.